# Can connect with PERL but can't query MSSQL 2k8 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, perl

I am able to connect to my MSSQL server but getting a permission error when trying
to query the database.  I see the "YAY" in the script below, but get this error:

> `*[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TICKET_TYPES', database 'DBNAME', schema 'dbo'. (SQL-42000)(DBD: st_execute/SQLExecute err=-1)*`

If I add "DOMAIN\DOMAIN Users" with DBO access it works, but when I take that away it doesn't.  I *think* it's connecting to the database as the logon user, not the SQL user that is set up in the connect string but not positive.

The SQL Driver is set to use "With SQL Server Authentication using a login ID..." and not "Windows NT..."

Classic ASP connects and queries fine.  I can access/query the DB using the SQL account in the connect string via ASP classic and SQL Server Management Studio.

It may be relevant that it also works perfectly against SQL2005 but not SQL2008 which we are trying to upgrade to.  Everything is fine with our upgrade except our couple Perl scripts just don't get into the tables.

```
use lib "cgi-bin";
use DBI;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
require "Babel.pm";

my $y          = new Babel;
my $q          = new CGI;

$SERVER_N = $q->server_name() ;

### CONNECT

  $database   = "DBNAME";
  $dbusername = "SQLUSERNAME";   
  $dbpassword = "SQLUSERPASSWORD";
  $server="SQLSERVERIP";  

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

   $dbh = DBI-> connect( "DBI:ODBC:driver={SQL Server};
                      Server=$server;
                  Database=$database;
                  UID=$dbusername;
                  PWD=$dbpassword")  || die &DBerror;                              

   if ($DBI::errstr) {print "Error: Connecting to the Database!";
             exit;}else{
             print "YAY! <br><br>";
   }  

### END: CONNECT

$v2SQL = "select distinct ROUTE from TICKET_TYPES";
        $css1 = $dbh->prepare ($v2SQL);
          $css1->execute ()  || print $css1->errstr;
          while ((@row) = $css1 ->fetchrow_array) {
            $MANA = @row[0];
            print "$MANA";
            }

          $css1->finish ()    || print $css1->errstr;
```

Comment: try using `system_user` to see who you are logged in as (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Laurence - I did that and it returns the logon name (Windows login, not SQL) but in that article it says "If the user name and login name are different, SYSTEM_USER returns the login name." so I am not positive that it is the login name.  And - if we can assume it is the login name - which makes sense as to why it's not letting me get to my table - how can I get it to execute the SQL using the SQL user name in my connect string?  That is really where I am looking.... many thanks!

Comment: It's always the login name (i.e. the thing you've authenticated using), however it might not be the database user.

Comment: Thanks Laurence - So how can I make sure the Perl is executing the SQL select statement as the SQL user in my connect string, so that I don't have to give permissions on the database to all of my domain users?  That's what I am after here - need to get past the Access Denied error without giving all domain users access.

Comment: See, I don't think it's an SQL/User issue at all because the user in my connect string can connect and execute commands in the db fine from the Server Management Studio.  (and from classic ASP) so it is a problem inherent only to Perl - or more so that Perl is executing the command as the logon user, not the user in the connect string (apparently).

Comment: With Perl DBI, try connecting by calling `connect($dsn, $user, $pass)` instead of having the username and password embedded in the connection string.

Comment: Thanks Stevenl.  I tried using this connect string.  It connected but I still got the same access denied error to the table.

Comment: my $dbs = "dbi:ODBC:DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={$server};Database={$database};";
my ($dbusername, $dbpassword) = ('username', 'password');

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dbs, $username, $password);    

if ($DBI::errstr) {print "Error: Connecting to the Database!";   
          exit;}else{   
          #print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";   
          print "YAY! In This way! <br><br>";   
}

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Stevenl's suggestion helped, but only in tandem with the fact that my password had an @ symbol that had to be escaped - like this p\@ssword.  Only when I did I used the new connect string format and the escaped @ did it execute the statement.

Comment: I guess I also learned that if SQL authentication fails, it then trys the LOGON user.  I got it to change from access denied to Password Failed with the new format.  If i gave all domain users access, it worked, even if the password failed (because of the non-escaped @).